# Publishing Linked Datasets Format

Tags: geojson, kml, database, matlab

This past summer for research I was working on linking the NOAA Rivers Database (http://water.weather.gov/ahps/forecasts.php), The National Atlas Lake Database, and the the USBGN datasets so that there were shapefiles for each lake or river in the dataset instead of just one (or two) points for each river/lake.

We linked them in MATLAB and now have this done and plan to publish it open source. Our linking does a more complete job than what's currently in TNA for linking lakes and we think this could be useful to others in the community. However, we're not sure what's the best method to publish this so that the most people could use it. Do you think KML or geoJSON would be best? Or as they are currently, an array of links matching the data together?

Comment: From what I see, most are using a combination of GeoJSON, CSV (with geometry) or Shapefile... Socrata (not FOSS), CKAN(http://extensions.ckan.org/extension/spatial/), etc. The Denver Data portal even publishes ESRI File Geodatabases... and CKAN spatial (link above) uses PostGIS as the back-end...

Comment: +1 for GeoJSON every time. It may not be self-describing, but it is most definitely developer friendly.